# hibernate/grails - exception on saving a string to long

Tags: hibernate, grails

I had a exception on saving my table:

ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Value too long for column MYSTRING VARCHAR(255)": "......(401)"

Should I absolutely add a constraint (max Size)?
If yes, my originally will take this constraint into account to avoid the exception?

**Domain:**

```
class MyClass {

   String myString

}
```

**Controller:**

```
def myString = params.q.toString()
def MyClassInstance = new MyClass (myString: myString)
MyClassInstance .save(flush: true)
```

Comment: You have map myString to TEXT or CLOB if it is expected to exceed varchar(255).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all String values in Grails are set to 255 characters. However, you can change this with a size constraint or map it to a TEXT or CLOB field.

### Option #1 (Constraint)

```
class MyClass {
  String myString
  static constraints = {
    myClass(blank: true, size:0..500) 
  }
}
```

The above example will allow zero to 500 characters, including blank.

### Option #2 (Mapping)

```
class MyClass {
  String myString
  static mapping = {
    myString type: 'text'
  }
}
```

The above example will use a TEXT field in your database instead of VARCHAR.